# IOS Facebook API User Status Returning NULL

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-fql, status

I am attempting to get a user's name, pic_square, and status object using the FQL statement:

It works great using the Graph API Explorer.  Here are the results:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": 657asdf, 
      "name": "Name1", 
      "pic_square": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc7/371062_657477736_1asd.jpg", 
      "status": {
        "message": "who want's to bring me a burrito?", 
        "time": 1349381334, 
        "status_id": "1015110984sadf", 
        "comment_count": 0
      }
    }, 
    {
      "uid": 123asdf, 
      "name": "name2", 
      "pic_square": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc6/275748_607345433_91234.jpg", 
      "status": {
        "message": "my excitement for tonight on a scale of 1-10 just went from a 15 to a 3 pretty quick", 
        "time": 1349386828, 
        "status_id": "1015216195asdf", 
        "comment_count": 0
      }
    },
```

But in Xcode I get the following result, notice the status is `<null>`:

```
data =     (
                {
            name = "Name1";
            "pic_square" = "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/371941_803145_672321642_q.jpg";
            status = "<null>";
            uid = 801asdf;
        },
                {
            name = "Name2";
            "pic_square" = "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/276004_2403715_8811asdf.jpg";
            status = "<null>";
            uid = 240asdf;
        },
```

Here is the code, which I ported [from here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/run-fql-queries-ios-sdk/)

```
NSString *query =
    @"SELECT uid, name, pic_square, status FROM user WHERE (uid IN "
   @"(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 1055)) ORDER BY status.time";

    NSDictionary *queryParam =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:query, @"q", nil];
    // Make the API request that uses FQL

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                                 parameters:queryParam
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {
                              if (error) {
                                  NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                              } else {
                                  NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);  

                              }
                          }];
```

Is this a limitation of the IOS Facebook API FBRequestConnection method? Is there an alternative approach?  I am sure I am not the only one trying to get both the user name and status in one FQL query.

Answer (score 0):

It was user error. I did not set the appropriate permissioning to get the status.  I had to include "frends_status" to the permissions array.

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"user_likes",
                            @"read_stream",
                            @"friends_status",
                            nil];
```